# Airflow Celery worker retries with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, airflow, celery

We are trying to setup CeleryExecutor for Airflow. The broker is configured in RabbitMQ (Three node cluster).

When we are starting the Airflow Celery Worker, we are seeing that it succeeds only after few retries. However, we are not able to figure out why? Has anyone faced a similar issue? This happens on every node where we are starting the worker.

```
[root@airflow-celery-abc-poc-8pvf ~]# export AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL=amqp://admin:admin@10.99.11.222:5672/abc_host
[root@airflow-celery-abc-poc-8pvf ~]# /usr/local/bin/airflow celery worker &
[1] 3009
[root@airflow-celery-abc-poc-8pvf ~]# [2023-04-17 18:21:38 +0000] [3020] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-04-17 18:21:38 +0000] [3020] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:840 SecurityWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this is
absolutely not recommended!

Please specify a different user using the --uid option.

User information: uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0


 -------------- celery@airflow-celery-abc-poc-8pvf v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Linux-3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.17 2023-04-17 18:21:39
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         airflow.executors.celery_executor:0x7f84c010c5b0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://admin:**@10.99.11.222:5672/abc_host
- ** ---------- .> results:     postgresql://abc-airflow-gce-dev-sa%40test_112233-abcuk-dev.iam@11.99.22.111:5433/airflowdb
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> default          exchange=default(direct) key=default


[tasks]
  . airflow.executors.celery_executor.execute_command

[2023-04-17 18:21:39 +0000] [3020] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-04-17 18:21:40 +0000] [3020] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-04-17 18:21:41 +0000] [3020] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-04-17 18:21:42 +0000] [3020] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-04-17 18:21:42,776: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://admin:**@10.99.11.222:5672/abc_host
[2023-04-17 18:21:42,790: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-04-17 18:21:43 +0000] [3020] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('::', 8793)
[2023-04-17 18:21:43,860: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: sync with 1 nodes
[2023-04-17 18:21:43,860: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: sync complete
[2023-04-17 18:21:43,936: INFO/MainProcess] celery@airflow-celery-abc-poc-8pvf ready.
```